# Calculation of item and quantity price then sending email

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms

I have a website where we are going to offer a few products for members to buy.
Please see http://jsfiddle.net/TbeQx/

```
<form action="" name="priceCalc" method="POST">
  I Am Paying For :
  <select name="product" onchange="price();">
      <option value="15">item 1 - $15.00</option>
      <option value="35">item 2 - $35.00</option>
      <option value="35">item 3 - $35.00</option>
      <option value="29.90">item 4 - $29.90</option>
      <option value="29.90">item 5 - $29.90</option>
      <option value="26.90">item 6 - $26.90</option>
      <option value="32.90">item 7 - $32.90</option>
      <option value="59.90">item 8 - $59.90</option>
      <option value="59.90">item 9 - $59.90</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <br />

    Quantity :
  <select name="quantity" onchange="price();">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <br />
    Please deposit the freight free full total of <br />
    <span style="color:red; font-size:18px;" id="prices">$</span> 
    into our account : 
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="BUY NOW!" />
</form>​

/* JavaScript */
    function price() {
        var qty = document.priceCalc.quantity;
        var itm = document.priceCalc.product;
        var price = parseInt(qty.value) * parseInt(itm.value);
        document.getElementById("prices").innerHTML = '$' + price;
    }​
```

How can I automatically calculate the price and display it between the id="prices" span tags onclick of both dropdowns.

This shows the user how much the total is.

Then on submitting, I need it to send an email to a designated email address saying..
"quantity" x "item name" = "qty"

(eg, 2 x item 4 - $29.90 = $59.80)

My php is here http://jsfiddle.net/8hzNV/

```
<?php
$quantity = $_POST["quantity"];
$item = $_POST["product"];
$subject = "Website Sale!";
$emailto = "myemail@test.com";


// prepare email body text
$body .= "";
$body .= "To Sales Team";
$body .= "\n";
$body .= "\n";
$body .= "I have purchased  ";
$body .= $quantity;
$body .= "x  ";
$body .= $item;
$body .= "\n";
$body .= "\n";
$body .= "Please look out for my payment in the account over the next few days.";

// send email 
$success = mail($emailto, $subject, $body");

// redirect to success page 
if ($success){
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=../order_sent.php\">";
}
else{
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=../index.php\">";
}

?>​
```

Ive had a go doing this myself. But this isnt my strong point and was hoping I could seek some expert advice.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Please post your code here, not on an external website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, Why don't you use jQuery selectors if you import jQuery to your project, It's more simple?

- You should use `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt`,
- You are just posting `Item Price` and `Item Quantity`, If you want to append Item name to email body you should post it also. So you can do this with intput[type=hidden]

## Here is the updated HTML

```
<form action="" name="priceCalc" method="POST">
  I Am Paying For :
  <select name="product">
      <option>Select Item</option>
       <option value="15">item 1 - $15.00</option>
       <option value="35">item 2 - $35.00</option>
       <option value="35">item 3 - $35.00</option>
       <option value="29.90">item 4 - $29.90</option>
       <option value="29.90">item 5 - $29.90</option>
       <option value="26.90">item 6 - $26.90</option>
       <option value="32.90">item 7 - $32.90</option>
       <option value="59.90">item 8 - $59.90</option>
       <option value="59.90">item 9 - $59.90</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <br />

    Quantity :
  <select name="quantity" >
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <br />
    Please deposit the freight free full total of <br />
    <span style="color:red; font-size:18px;" id="prices">$</span> into our account : 
    <br />
    <input type="hidden" id="itemname" name = "itemname" value= "">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="BUY NOW!" />
</form>​
```

You don't need to set inline function price(),

## Here is the JavaScript code updated with jQuery selectors

```
$(function() {
    $("select[name='product'],select[name='quantity']").change(function() {
        var qty = $("select[name='quantity'] option:selected");
        var itm = $("select[name='product'] option:selected");
        var price = parseFloat(qty.val()) * parseFloat(itm.val());
        $("#prices").html('$' + price);
        $("#itemname").val(itm.html());
    });
});
​
```

And in PHP page you should get $itemname from POST array,

## PHP page should be like this,

```
<?php
    $quantity = $_POST["quantity"];
    $item = $_POST["product"];
    $itemname = $_POST["itemname"];
    $subject = "Website Sale!";
    $emailto = "myemail@test.com";


    // prepare email body text
    $body .= "";
    $body .= "To Sales Team";
    $body .= "\n";
    $body .= "\n";
    $body .= "I have purchased  ";
    $body .= $quantity;
    $body .= "x  ";
    $body .= $itemname;
    $body .= " = ";
    $body .= $item * $quantity;
    $body .= "\n";
    $body .= "\n";
    $body .= "Please look out for my payment in the account over the next few days.";

    // send email 
    $success = mail($emailto, $subject, $body");

    // redirect to success page 
    if ($success){
      print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=../order_sent.php\">";
    }
    else{
      print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=../index.php\">";
    }

?>​
```